# Why is jQuery AJAX working in browser but not in Electron?

Tags: jquery, ajax, elasticsearch, electron

I am trying to convert my web page to a desktop app. In the web, I make and ajax call to an elastic search server get some data and load it to the dropdown. It is working properly on the web, but when I make it a desktop app, the ajax call is not working.

```js
// main.js
const electron = require('electron');
const { app, BrowserWindow } = electron;

let mainWindow;

app.on('ready', () => {
    mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
        width: 1000,
        height: 700
    });

    mainWindow.setTitle('title of the desktop app');
    mainWindow.loadURL('http://localhost/tac/');

    mainWindow.on('closed', () => {
        mainWindow = null;
    });
});
```

```html
// index.html

<body>
<div>
    <button id = "btnSubmit">Connect to ES</button>
    <select name="drop_down" id="dropDownCars">
        <option value="None" selected="Selected">Select type</option>
    </select>

    </div>
</body>
```

```js
// esCall.js
$(document).ready(function () {
  $("#btnSubmit").click(function () {
    alert("hi");
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "http://localhost:9200/company/_search",
      contentType: "application/json",
      dataType: "json",
      success: function (data) {
        console.log(data);
        var csv = "",
          keys;
        if (data != "") {
          alert("data not null");
          data = data.hits.hits;
          final_from_index = data;
          var list,
            elements,
            index,
            final = [],
            keys = "",
            values = "",
            buf = "",
            field,
            buf1 = new Object(),
            arr = [];
          final = [];
          for (i in data) {
            list = data[i];
            if (list._index != "results") {
              console.log(list._index);

              for (j in list) {
                index = list._index;
                if (j == "_source") {
                  elements = list[[j]];
                  elements.index = index;
                  keys = Object.keys(elements);
                  values = Object.values(elements);
                  buf = "";
                  for (k in keys) {
                    if (k == keys.length - 1) {
                      buf += values[k];
                    } else {
                      buf += values[k] + " , ";
                    }
                  }
                  elements.text = buf;
                  final.push(elements);
                }
              }
            }
          }
          alert(final.length);
          console.log(final);
          $.each(final, function (key, value) {
            $("#dropDownCars").append("<option>" + value.name + "</option>");
          });
        }
      },
    });
  });
});
```

Is there anything specific I need to do to make ajax work in electron app. Appreciate all your help!

Comment: On the 4th line of esCall.js you have `alert("hi")`. Is that getting triggered?

Comment: yes hi is alerted..but the alerts inside ajax call not triggered.

Comment: add a failure callback and log the output `error: (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) => (console.log(textStatus, errorThrown))`